# Find the derivative of the function $y=2^{x+1}$

Tags: derivatives

The function is $y=2^{x+1}$, and I need to find the derivative of the function. I solved it using the derivative rule $$\frac{dy}{dx}(a^x)= a^x (\ln a): dy/dx= 2^{x+1}\ln 2$$ But the answer is $2 \ln 2(2^x)$.

Anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: Those are the same.  $2^{x+1}=2\times 2^x$.

Comment: Oops yup you're right they're the same thing